# Function to delete dynamically allocated 2D array

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, heap-memory, delete-operator

Quick question here. Using this func to allocate memory for an arr:

```
int **createDynamicNumArray() {
int size;
cout << "Enter size: " << endl;
cin >> size;
int **numArr = new int *[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    numArr[i] = new int[size];
}
return numArr;
}
```

Is this the correct way for a function to clear said memory?:

```
void delArr(int **&numArr, int size) {
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    delete[] numArr[i];
}
delete[] numArr;
}
```

Key note: Do I pass just a double pointer or a double pointer reference to the function for deleting?

Thank you in advance

Comment: FWIW, if you use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>> numArr(size, std::vector<int>(size))` you don't need to worry about cleaning anything up.

Comment: [X-Y answer](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op)

Comment: No need for reference in this case unless you want to change where the caller's pointer points. Just having the pointer is sufficient to delete the object at the pointer.

Comment: To directly answer the (first) question: Yes, that would work.  But it would resemble C code, in a language that has gone to great lengths to eliminate the need for bug-prone memory micro-management like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this the correct way for a function to clear said memory?:

Yes.

> Key note: Do I pass just a double pointer or a double pointer reference to the function for deleting?

Both work. I recommend not using a reference since that will be less confusing to the reader.

---

However, I recommend avoiding owning bare pointers in the first place. In this case, `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` could be appropriate.

Or, more efficient (probably; depends on how you intend to use it) alternative would be to use a single dimensional vector and translate the indices.

Comment: [Very simple example of a `std::vector`-based 1D matrix as mentioned in the last paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301).